# How to train/upscale a very large dataset using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm using the sentiment140 dataset which consists of 1.6M tweets to train and analyze the accuracies of different classifiers in the scikit-learn library in python. I am using the following code snippet to vectorize the tweets into feature vectors before feeding them to the classifiers.

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features = 2000)
train_set = (vectorizer.fit_transform(trainX)).toarray()
```

After this I train my `classifier` object which includes `GaussianNB()`, `MultinomialNB()`, `BernoulliNB()`, `LogisticRegression()`, `LinearSVC()` and `RandomForestClassifier()` using the following code snippet:

```
classifier.fit(train_vectors,trainy)
```

However, on converting my vectorizer's transformed set to a numpy array with the `toarray()` function for the `trainset`, I see that the program is using up a great deal of memory (about 4-5 GB) for just 100k examples with a feature vector of size 2000 for each example, i.e., a 100,000x2000 feature vector.

This is the maximum my system can do since I only have 8GB of RAM. Can someone give suggestions as to how I may proceed so as to be able to train the entire 1.6M of the training dataset with the available memory by possibly modifying the code anyhow. If I try to do with the above code it would require around 72 gigs of RAM which is not feasible.

I also understand there are provisions to incrementally train certain classifiers with a fraction of the train set iteratively. Classifiers such as `MultinomialNB()` and `BernoulliNB()` have provisions for that (using `partial_fit`) but the other classifiers that I'm also using don't, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, what are you trying to achieve in the first place? The reason I'm asking is, that vectorized text has a large number of dimensions by the very nature of the problem. Furthermore `max_features=2000` isn't going to get you anywhere near an adequate performance in text classification.

Long story short: Most of the classifiers you mentioned work with sparse vectors, except `GaussianNB`, this can be easily verified with:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target

for CLF in [GaussianNB, MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB, LogisticRegression, LinearSVC, GradientBoostingClassifier]:
    print(CLF.__name__, end='')
    try:
        CLF().fit(csr_matrix(X), y == 0)
        print(' PASS')
    except TypeError:
        print(' FAIL')
```

Which outputs:

```
GaussianNB FAIL
MultinomialNB PASS
BernoulliNB PASS
LogisticRegression PASS
LinearSVC PASS
GradientBoostingClassifier PASS
```

I suggest, that you simply drop `GaussianNB` from your list and work with the classifiers that support sparse vectors. You should at least be able to work with more samples within your 8g limit.

See also [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6440) for scikit-learn, quoting Jake Vanderplas:

> One reason sparse inputs are not implemented in `GaussianNB` is that very sparse data almost certainly does not meet the assumptions of the algorithm – when the bulk of the values are zero, a simple Gaussian is not a good fit to the data, and will almost never lead to a useful classification.

Comment: Thank you! I never knew that these classifiers worked with sparse arrays. Since I tested with the GaussianNB() classifier before others, for which I had to do a conversion of train set to numpy array, I implicitly thought that I needed to do the same for other classifiers as well. Removing GaussianNB takes away the necessity to make the sparse array I get  from fit_transform to a dense array and hence solves my problem.

Comment: As for your question, I am aware that using a featureset of 2000 words won't give me a good accuracy. I was getting accuracies in the range of 74-77% using the algorithms. But I had no choice since using a large feature set caused memory overflow. But your solution helped me use a larger feature set without memory problems so thanks once again.

Comment: Perfect, glad I could help. :)